# How does a buck converter maximize the power in the MPPT system?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, solar-energy, buck-boost, solar-charge-controller, mppt

How can a DC-DC buck converter be used to maximize input power in an MPPT system? I know that an MPPT system consists of a processor that reads the power source and manages a buck converter to maximize the power. However, I've been thinking: how can a buck do this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking

Comment: Do you know the I/V curve of a solar panel, and what it means?

Comment: In the case of an MPPT battery charge controller, I believe the typical way this is done is to adjust the duty cycle of the buck while measuring output voltage and current until the buck converter output power is maximized. In principal you could also read input voltage and current, and maximize input power. Doesn't really make much difference which one you maximize.

Comment: For MPPT grid-tie inverters, the quantity to be maximized is output current.

Answer (score 4):

From the datasheet of the panels on my roof:

[image]

At low output voltage, current is constant: the panel behaves like a current source proportional to illumination. Since P=U*I, this means you want it to output the maximum possible voltage to get maximum power, as shown by the upwards slope on the power curve.

However these panels are a series of diodes, so when output voltage becomes high enough, the diodes conduct and the current that was just produced by the panel flows back into the photodiodes. Basically, if you leave the output open, the panel will output maximum voltage, dissipate all the power it produces, and therefore produce no useful power.

So there is a maximum power point corresponding to a specific current and voltage for each value of illumination. It also moves around a bit with temperature. To get maximum power you have to operate the panel at an output voltage corresponding to the peak on the P-V curve above (bottom plot).

The type of converter to use for a MPPT depends on the relationship between the panels' output voltage and the voltage you actually want at the output of your MPPT. So if you have a 40V panel and you want to charge a 12V battery, you'd use a buck to lower voltage. If you have several panels making 240V in series and you need 330V DC to power an inverter, then you'd use a boost. And if you have one 40V panel and you want to make a micro-inverter that outputs 230VAC, you'd use a transformer-based converter to boost 40V to 330V (because a boost converter would be inefficient at this large input:output ratio) then a DC to AC inverter.

The important thing about the converter is that it should have a high efficiency (ie, switching, not a linear regulator) and it should work well with a current source as input.

The panel behaves as a current source, so the converter is current-fed. The output of the MPPT converter is usually a battery of a DC bus with lots of capacitance on it. These two points are important:

- Since it is current-fed, you don't want a converter that regulates its input or output current, because that would fight the current source nature of the panels.
- Because the load has very low dynamic impedance, there is no point in having an inner loop trying to regulate the output voltage. It will change too slowly to be usable.

Several implementations are possible, but you'll usually find a microcontroller or a DSP somewhere, because the algorithm needs control loops that would be difficult to do with analog.

A possible implementation is to make a converter that regulates its input voltage to a target value. This may sound weird, and it wouldn't work if powered by a voltage source (like a battery) but it works fine when powered by a current source (a solar panel). So, when input voltage rises, the converter will adjust its duty cycle to consume more current. When input voltage falls, it will decrease its duty cycle to consume less current. The actual control law depends on the type of converter. This inner loop's setpoint (target input voltage) is then adjusted by a slower outer feedback loop that calculates power, varies the voltage setpoint a little bit, figures out which way results in more power, and adjusts accordingly.

Another way would be to blindly vary the duty cycle up and down, check which way gives more power, and go in that direction.

Some converters sometimes pause to make a sweep through the whole I-V curve and then pick the maximum. This can be useful because if there is shadow on some of your panels, the IV curve can be quite wiggly with several peaks.

There are many different algos. I suggest searching "MPPT algorithms".

If the output voltage is fixed or varies slowly because it's on a battery, then "maximizing power" is the same as maximizing the converter's DC output current, which is simpler.

It should also implement other features like ensuring the output voltage or inductor current do not rise to unsafe values, taking into account the maximum charging current of the battery depending on its state of charge, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## First Understand the MPPT Principle

So, the problem is that, as the solar irradiance from the sun changes due to clouds, or the angle of the sun, or what part of the season it is, the solar panel will change it's voltage output, and also change the maximum power that it is capable of.  Power is V*I, and when V=0 then power is zero, and when I=0 then power is zero, so somewhere between open circuit and short-circuit is the best point, where you get the max power out of the solar panel (which changes at any given moment). It turns out that the max power point is at the knee of the graph, when the V-I curve starts to plummet (but as we said, as clouds go by, that curve moves around all the time).

All of the following curves come from the following datasheet for a 12 volt 100W solar panel found here:

https://renogy.com/content/RNG-100D-SS/RNG-100D-SS%20G3%20Datasheet.pdf

For what lies ahead, know that the power output is the **area** of the rectangle under the curve corresponding to V*I.

So, for the following curve (considering only the highest curve):

[image]

If a DC-DC converter tries to extract the energy from the panel like this:

[image]

you get only about 5V x 5.2A = 26 Watts.

If a DC-DC converter tries to extract the energy from the panel like this:

[image]

you get only about 24V x 1A = 24 Watts.

But with an MPPT charge controller, it will extract the energy from a solar panel more like this:

[image]

giving you somewhere about 20V x 5A = 100 Watts. We've maximized our power output, so we've found the Maximum Power Point (for this particular irradiance and set of conditions).

## How Does the Buck Converter Hit an MPPT Point?

The buck converter has to actually change something in order to get performance of the solar panel at the desired power point (point on the graph) -- 20V x 5A = 100W.

We can't change the output voltage of the panel -- it is the panel that decides what voltage it outputs, based upon the level of sun (irradiance), the temperature, the angle of the sun, how old the panel is, how much dirt is on the glass, etc. The solar panel also decides its output voltage on how much current is drawn out, by the "resistor" that is "presented" to the solar panel.

We can control the impedance (frequency dependent resistance) that we **present** to the solar panel, by choosing the PWM percentage (duty cycle). PWM alternates turning a transistor all the way on, then all the way off, and the percentage of on-time to off-time determines the impedance that is **seen** by the solar panel, which determines how much current flows at the current voltage, which makes the panel change its output voltage according to the VI curves shown above.

The solar panel also has its own internal resistance, the same way a battery has an internal resistance. When you draw out high power the voltage falls the most. When you draw out just a little power, the voltage stays the highest.

The panel changes its output voltage **in response to** the particular amperage that the buck converter is extracting.

So then, one method of doing this is as follows:  (I think this is called [Purturb and Observe](https://www.google.com/search?q=solar%20%22purturb%20and%20observe%22%20MPPT&oq=&aqs=)): Every so often...
Draw a little **more** current and see if the power out goes up. If it does, follow that trend until the power doesn't go up.
Then follow the converse:
Draw a little **less** current and see if the power out goes up. If it does, follow that trend until the power doesn't go up.
Then, go to sleep another 100ms to 500ms and try again.

So the buck converter **increases** its draw on the solar panel by drawing out more current, or presenting more of a short-circuit (providing a lower impedance path so more current flow can happen). This is generally done with pulse-width modulation switching a transistor on and off, where 100% on is a short-circuit, and 0% on is open circuit, and anything between that gives the average corresponding to the % on-time.

If the buck converter is asked to increase its power draw (to allow the voltage to fall a little), it will increase the percentage of on-time in the PWM signal to the MOSFET transistor. With the higher percentage of on-time, the transistor draws more current out of the solar panel, which causes the voltage output from the panel to fall. The solar panel V*I is recalculated for the next iteration.

If the buck converter is asked to decrease its power draw (to allow the voltage to rise a little), it will decrease the percentage of on-time in the PWM signal to the MOSFET transistor. With the lower percentage of on-time, the transistor draws less current out of the solar panel, which causes the voltage output from the panel to rise. The solar panel V*I is recalculated for the next iteration.

Comment: When you say "f you "turn up" the buck converter and withdraw more power, the voltage will fall", this isn't consistent with your table of values.  Ie if we start at 15 V, we get more power **and** more voltage if we go up to 25V.  This is the whole essence of MPPT.  In solar panels the MPP is usually near the open-circuit voltage.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a microprocessor controlling the duty cycle of a buck converter, all you need to do is vary the duty cycle to find the point at which the buck output power is maximized. Of course actual implementations have to deal with many more details but this is the most basic version of it.

For a single panel or string of panels with no shading, there is exactly one duty cycle which will yield the maximum output power for the buck converter. This will occur at or very near the point where the solar panel output is at its maximum.

So in theory you could maximize the solar panel output instead of the buck converter output. The two operating points will be identical or very close together. But since you already have to monitor the buck converter output voltage and current, it is probably easier to just monitor and maximize that.

There is more than one algorithm for how to vary the duty cycle so that it tracks the maximum power point.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I've been thinking: how can a buck do this?

It can't do it on it's own, you must have a digital or analog control loop to vary the voltage if its a VCVS (which is usually the case) or the current.

The first step is calculating power. This must be done with some kind of multiplication or equivalent, and measuring voltage and current from the panel.

Usually some kind of startup sequence is needed to get the power to a point away from max current or max voltage.

There are a few algorithms that can be used to then find the peak power point, since this is always changing for most solar applications and the load is changing, it must be recalculated.

- Perturb and observe: The power differential of now vs what is was perviously is calculated. Then the voltage differential is calculated. You then move the voltage up or down based on both of these. This one is very easy to implement on FPGA's and microprocessors. (once did one of these for a satellite MPPT with a FPGA and a linear regulator)
- Incremental conductance:

> This algorithm, shown below, compares the
> incremental conductance to the instantaneous conductance in a PV
> system. Depending on the result, it increases or decreases the voltage
> until the maximum power point (MPP) is reached. Unlike with the P&O
> algorithm, the voltage remains constant once MPP is reached.

- Fractional open-circuit voltage:

> This algorithm is based on the
> principle that the maximum power point voltage is always a constant
> fraction of the open circuit voltage. The open circuit voltage of the
> cells in the photovoltaic array is measured and used as in input to
> the controller.

https://www.mathworks.com/solutions/power-electronics-control/mppt-algorithm.html

Answer (score -3):

You are absolutely right, Buck can never do MPPT. Two simple reasons:

1- When buck's duty cycle is in off state, it is not drawing any power from solar panel and hence it is a waste.

2- Buck cannot increase the current. eg: A 500W solar panel delivering 12A at 40V, using a buck controller can never charge a battery at 12V with 40A.

Comment: Every sentence is wrong.

Comment: @winny Just saying "wrong" is not enough. You will need to prove it.

Comment: Please google “buck MPPT”. Zero hits? Zero products? Zero master thesis reports and PhD dissertations? Please google “buck output current” in the same manner.

Comment: @winny Your best bet would be to use an input capacitor, but you will lose MPPT between fluctuation of capacitor voltage during charge and discharge. Further the optimum C value of the input capacitor will depend upon the availability of solar power(cloudy, morning, afternoon, evening cases). Having a dynamic value of C is not easy ( almost impossible).

Comment: No such thing. Please simulate it.